# what is meant by time based spliting in cross validation techniques?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, cross-validation

I have a timestamp for every record in the data set.

I heard about time based spiting but don't know anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Normal cross-validation

You have a set of data points:

```
data_points = [2, 4, 5, 8, 6, 9]
```

Then, if you do a 2-fold split, your data points will get **randomly** assigned to 2 different groups.

For example:

```
split_1 = [2, 5, 9]
split_2 = [3, 8, 6]
```

However, this assumes that there is no need to keep the o*rder of your data points*.
You can train your model with `split_1` and test it with `split_2`.

## Time based splitting

However, this assumption isn't always correct for time series prediction.

For example, given the same data points:

```
data_points = [2, 4, 5, 8, 6, 9]
```

It can be that they are arranged by time.

You could then have a model that to predict the next number, it looks back 3 time steps. (e.g. to predict the number after `9`, it will have `[8, 6, 9]` as input. Meaning that the order of which the data points appear is important. Because of that, in order to test your model, you cannot randomly split your data points. **The order in which they appear needs to be kept**.

So if you do a 2-fold split, you could get the following splits:

```
split_1 = [2, 4, 5, 8]
split_2 = [5, 8, 6, 9]
```

## Implementation

There is an implementation of time-based cross-validation from Sklearn: the [TimeSeriesSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html).

Comment: What is the benefit of the time based spiltitng?

Comment: The benefit is that you can split time series in a way that that the time component integrity is maintained. Normal cross-validation splits do not take into account the time.